# Derivative of Limit cycle

Tags: derivatives

I encountered the following function in Numerical Methods, where y is 2 by 1 Vector:

[image: The limit cycle function]

You can see the Jacobian of y here:

[image: Jacobian]

You can also see the eigenvalues of jacobian Function where |y|=1:

[image: Eigenvalues]

I tried to take the derivative and find the eigenvectors myself but my lack of analysis knowledge maybe made it hard for me to do it, I would really appreciate it when somebody explain this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the lines of $f(y)$ we have

$$
\frac{d f(y)}{d y_k}=\frac{d}{dy_k}\left(A_{ij}y_j+\lambda\left(1-\sum_{l=1}^3y_l^2\right)y_i\right)
$$

and now

$$
\frac{d}{dy_k}A_{ij}y_j = A_{ik}e_k\\
\frac{d}{dy_k}\left(1-\sum_{l=1}^3y_l^2\right)y_i = \left(1-\sum_{l=1}^3y_l^2\right)e_k-2y_k y_i e_k
$$

here $e_k$ represents the $k-$row unit. So we have

$$
\frac{d}{dy_k}\left(A_{ij}y_j+\lambda\left(1-\sum_{l=1}^3y_l^2\right)y_i\right)
= A_{ik}e_k+\left(1-\sum_{l=1}^3y_l^2\right)e_k-2y_k y_i e_k
$$

or in a more compact form

$$
Df(y) = A+\lambda \left(1-||y||^2\right)I_3-2\lambda y y^{\top}
$$

with $I_3$ the identity rank 3 matrix.

Now regarding the eigenvalues

substituting into $Df(y)$ the relationship $y_1 = \sqrt{1-y_2}$ we have

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 \lambda  \left(y_2^2-1\right) & -2 \lambda  \sqrt{1-y_2^2} y_2-1 \\
 1-2 \lambda  y_2 \sqrt{1-y_2^2} & -2 \lambda  y_2^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with eigenvalues

$$
\left\{-\sqrt{\lambda ^2-1}-\lambda ,\sqrt{\lambda ^2-1}-\lambda \right\}
$$